# Instagram Insight Metrics with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Facebook Graph API to GET Instagram metrics such as post impressions. I was able to successfully pull my Instagram Follow Count by using this query

```
{instagram_user_id}?fields=follow_count
```

When I try to query my post impressions with

```
{instagram-media-id}/insights?fields=post_impressions
```

nothing shows up. Am I missing something or have I possibly not requested the correct permissions?

I am trying to follow the documentation at the below link. Is it even possible to pull the impressions through the Facebook Graph API?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-media/insights/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it wasn't possible to pull insights using the older version of the API.

However now it is possible as instagram / facebook just released a new version of their Graph API that includes insights. The request would be:

```
v2.10/{instagram_media_id}/insights?metric=impressions
```

The new documentation can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/instagram-api/v2.10)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify "period" parameter? By default it might not be a "lifetime" and if you did not generate any impression recently you will see nothing (empty array i assume). In case you missing some permissions, Facebook will make you aware in response.